# Verifying two different build architectures (one a re-write of the other) are functionally equivalent

Tags: object, build-process, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm re-writing a build that produces a number of things (shared/static libraries, jars, executables, etc).  The question came up whether there's a way to verify that the results are functionally equivalent without doing a full top-to-bottom test of the resulting software.

However, that is proving to be more difficult to do than I anticipated.

As an example, I expected that the md5 of two objects produced from the same source (sun studio C++ compiler) and command-line parameters would have the same md5 hash, but that isn't the case.  I can build the file, rename it, build again, and they have different hashes.

With that said ... is there a way do a quick check to verify that two files produced from separate build architectures of the same source tree (eg, two shared objects) are functionally equivalent?

*edit* I am sorry, I neglected to mention this is for a debug build ... when debugging flags aren't used the binaries are identical, but they've been using debugging flags by default for so many years their stuff breaks when you remove the debugging flags (part of the reason I'm re-writing the build is to take that particular 'feature' out of the build so we can get some proper testing going)

Comment: The puzzling thing that I see here is that the usage of debug-flags  altering the output in relation to another built with the same debug-flag. As such, I would venture to say that your setup cannot be safely tested as one input (a set of source files) does NOT produce the same output all the time. {e.g. your build-process is not 'functional' in that one input produces multiple outputs.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question; I'm revisiting so I can give the answer I came up with.

[objcopy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) can be used to produce a new binary file in different formats.  It's been a few years since I worked on this, so the specifics escape me, but here's what I recall:

`objcopy` can strip various things out (debug info, symbol information, etc), but even after stripping stuff out I was still seeing different hashes between objects.

In the end I found I could convert it from ELF to other formats.  I ended up dumping it to another format (I think I chose SREC) that consistently provided the same MD5 for objects built at different times with identical source/flags.

I'm betting I could have done this a better way with `objcopy` (or perhaps another `binutils` tool), but it was good enough to satisfy our concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Windows DLLs have a link timestamp ([TimeDateStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)) as part of PE image.

Looking at [linker options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx), I don't see an option to suppress that. So re-linking a DLL (or an EXE) will always produce a different binary.

You could write a tool to zero out these timestamps (always at a fixed offset from file start), and compare MD5s  afterwards. But you'll likely discover lots of other differences as well. In particular, any program that uses `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` builtins will give you trouble.

We've had to work quite hard to achieve bit-identical rebuilds (using GNU toolchain). It's possible (at least for open-source tools, on Linux), but not easy (as you've discovered).

Comment: I've just discovered something even more puzzling.  Using the sun studio toolset, if I build without debug flags the object files (using `-c`) still contain symbols that differ between builds unless I pass in `-s` to strip symbols.  In Linux, even that doesn't help (probably indicating a bug in the Linux implementation of the `-s` functionality in the SS toolset)