# How do you programmatically determine build system equivalence in binary output?

Tags: c++, c, linux, open-source, build-process

**Background:** Assume you have two servers acting as build servers (Jenkins if it matters) for C/C++ code.  Both servers have been built with identical kickstarts, OS versions, libraries, etc. The code is maintained in Git on two branches - Development and Release Candidate.  The code in Development is authoritative and elevated to RC.  Git hashes match. Code built on dev infrastructure produces functioning binaries. Code produced on RC infrastructure does not (or at least in testing, appears to have bugs not witnessed on Dev). How would you go about proving that the build of Dev and the build of RC are identical.  What tools would you use? What would you check?  What metrics would you capture?  How do other software companies do thsi?  This is not a theoretical exercise - I am being forced to prove this.  Have read [Verifying two different build architectures (one a re-write of the other) are functionally equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196998/verifying-two-different-build-architectures-one-a-re-write-of-the-other-are-fu).  OS is RHEL 6.2.

Comment: What do you mean by "built on **dev** *infrastructure*" vs "built on **RC** *infrastructure*"? Emphasis 'infrastructure'.

Comment: As I state below, we have separate servers for dev and RC.  They are VMs on the same stock hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are two different builds, presumably with different compiler options and defines, it's very unlikely that they are the same.

However step 1 would be to change the RC build configuration to match the dev configuration. If the resulting binaries aren't the same, that may provide some insight as to differences in the build environment. Most people call this configuration "Beta".

Step 2 would be to create an intermediate build which has the Dev build configuration but the RC defines. Confirm that the binaries differ - there is likekly to be some #ifdef'd code that behaves differently under RC.

The idea is to go to both machines and do the equivalent of:

```
cd $BUILD
mkdir dev-bin beta-bin prerc-bin
make dev && mv $BINARIES dev-bin
make beta && mv $BINARIES beta-bin
make prerc && mv $BINARIES prerc-bin
```

Diff and proffit. You can repeat across build boxes.

I'm puzzled why you have a separate build environment for each stage. That seems guaranteed to fail you on a periodic basis.

My most successful experiences have always been to develop a specific build across it's range of iterations in a given build directory.

1. Create working copy from source control,
2. Build Dev -> Test,
3. If fixes: apply, goto step 2,
4. Build RC -> Test,
5. If fixes: apply, goto step 2,
6. Build Rel

Obviously this has to be backed up by some degree of manual workflow control so that new features don't keep dropping in and resetting you to step 2 (What? The guy was working till 5am, of course he checked it in to the production branch without testing it)

Comment: Different servers mainly to separate load.  Fundamentally, any build can occur on any build server.  There are no changes to compiler options or defines.

Comment: Ok - the way you presented it made it sound like you have to distinct, targeted build systems - one for dev one for RC, and that would certainly have made me task an employee/colleague with proving that they were the same. Make sure you haven't given the same impression internally.

Answer (score 0):

If there are different preprocessor directives, and different compiling options, then most likely they are not identical.
The different environment itself could be another factor contributing to the different behavior.

If you see different behavior than I'm sorry to tell you, that there probably is a bug, and you need to solve it.

If someone's telling you to prove they are identical just because they don't believe there's a bug, then tell them they're wrong, and the facts show otherwise.

Comment: Compilers, chips, and machines are identical as are the contents of the make files, compiler flags and linkers.  I wish telling them to prove it was an option.

Comment: @DavidL if they were truely identical, a simple "diff" would do the job. I guess that isn't so ?

Comment: A simple diff of...? The binaries? We are looking at that but a diff of the binaries thus far are not showing any differences. We are actually investigating, using 'readelf' and 'objdump' of the .o files to see if there is anything in them that will give us what we need. But then we get into issues of memory pointers.

Comment: Well, if the diff of the binaries are identical then the files are identical. It's just the environment then.

Comment: When you say the "diff of the binaries is the same," you mean in the sense that md5sum(Dev Binary) == md5sum(RC Binary)?